# TestCafe runs tests twice

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, web-testing

I am using TestCafe for some time now and never had a problem. A few days ago TestCafe started to run my tests twice, producing a lot of problems. I couldn't find the issue on https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues and wanted to ask if anyone else experienced these problems in the last time.

I am always starting the tests with: 'testcafe "chrome --start-fullscreen" tests/tests --speed 0.5 --skip-js-errors'.

Thank you so much and best regards from Germany

Stefan

Comment: The command to run TestCafe tests looks correct. I guess the problem is not related to TestCafe.
Could you please provide an example with which it's possible to reproduce the problem locally?

Comment: Hi Alex, so sorry that I didn't get back to you sooner! I have a new problem by now. I just wrote a new test for our CMS. When I start the fixture with only one test it succeeds but if I add one more test case the test fails complaining 'No tests to run. Either the test files contain no tests or the filter function is too restrictive.' Do you have any idea what could cause that? :)

Comment: @Stefan, it sounds like you have a syntax error in your test code. I recommend that you create a new question and post your test code. Please do not mix several inquiries in one thread to avoid any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I face this issue, whenever i am on same terminal with multiple interrupted run. Close your terminal

Comment: Thank you so much! I will definitively test it out! :-)